# diff for multiple files

Tags: diff

I use "diff -y" command to compare 2 results of different versions of my program line by line. Like this:

```
1      1
123  | 234
asdf | qerq
```

Is there analog for multiple files, which will allow to compare line by line 3 or 4 files?Like this:

```
1      1      1      1
123  | 234  | 345  | 234
asdf | qerq | qdfd | asdd
```

Answer (score 10):

[vimdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vimdiff) 1 2 3 4;

[image: vimdiff]

It's highly customisable with loads of features, for example if you want to dump the UI to html;

```
vimdiff 1 2 3 4 -c TOhtml -c 'w! diff4.html|qa!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice [suggestion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time). Take a look at the accepted answer about [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) software.

As for the output of the comparison to a file, I've just tested it with **diffuse-0.4.6**, but was unable to discover such feature, so I guess it's a topic for another question...

Comment: Em.... I don't get it. I ask about three and more..

Comment: Sorry, my bad... Now I understand what you need... [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time)

Comment: Thanks. If you change your answer I would accept it. But, is there a way to dump result in the file? So I can send it to other people?

Answer (score 0):

There is [diff3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff3) for comparing three files

Comment: It shows only different parts and delete similar parts of the files. Or this can be changed?