# How to diff three binary files to show only what changed between 1 and 2 and then changed back between 2 and 3?

Tags: linux, diff, binary-files, file-comparison

I have three binary files (memory dumps). Call them `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.
I'm trying to debug some software, and I'm toggling a switch.

- `file1` = switch off
- `file2` = switch on
- `file3` = switch off

I need to know which bytes changed between `file1` and `file2`, which then also changed back to the same values (as `file1`) in `file3`.

There are a lot of unrelated changes between `file1`, `file2` so that `diff` alone is not enough for me to determine what is changing when I toggle this switch, I'm trying to identify the unique bytes of entropy that change from `file1`,`2`,`3`,…

I know there are tools such as `xxd`, `diff`, `vimdiff`, `colordiff`. I'm just not sure how best to use them for this problem.

Comment: "`diff` alone is not enough" – General note: tools that work with text (lines) cannot handle binary (i.e. non-text) input nicely. Even if they can in some cases, their output may not be what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare binary files in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/125376/150988)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three way binary comparison for savegame hacking](https://superuser.com/q/708461/150988).   Unfortunately, the only answer is a program that’s not free ($30 through $60, depending).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [diff for multiple files](https://superuser.com/q/508608/150988).

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you want. Can you give an example? It should be long enough to illustrate all the aspects that are important, but short enough to be comprehensible.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some guidance.

Comment: I can't think of a tool for this; the quickest way would be to write a real small program that does it (couple of dozen lines at most).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know bytes that changed between `file1` and `file2` and their respective values, use `cmp -l`:

```
cmp -l file1 file2 > changes12
```

Similarly for `file3` and `file2`. The trick is to always investigate in the same direction (here: switch off to on), that's why I put `file2` at the end:

```
cmp -l file3 file2 > changes32
```

Now you can find identical changes:

```
comm -12 changes12 changes32
```

and the output will be like (example):

```
     1629 152 112
```

which means the byte `1629` (decimal, numbering starts with `1`) changed from `152` (octal) to `112` (octal).

---

Notes:

- `cmp -l` in my Ubuntu "columnizes" its output. This means it may print lines with leading spaces, the width of the first column depends on the input size. I guess some implementations may not do this. There are few concerns:

  - If the original files are of different size (probably not your case), one `cmp` may generate wider first column than the other. In the context of later `comm` this is unacceptable. You can "decolumnize" the output by piping to `awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}'`.
  - If the output is not "columnized" (or has been "decolumnized"), `comm` may complain the files are not sorted. You need `sort` (not `sort -n`) before you save to `changesAB`. This may generate somewhat unexpected order (e.g. differing byte `23` will appear *after* differing byte `100453`) which may be fixed by piping the output of `comm` to `sort -n`.
- `changes*` files may be huge. They are intermediate and temporary, so process substitution may be a good approach. This is non-POSIX though:

  ```
  # Korn shell syntax example
  comm -12 <(cmp -l file1 file2) <(cmp -l file3 file2)
  ```
- The output from `comm` can be used with yet another and another output of `cmp` to filter out unrelated changes better:

  ```
  comm -12 changes12 changes32 > result1
  cmp -l file4 file5 | comm -12 - result1 > result2
  cmp -l file6 file5 | comm -12 - result2 > result3
  ```

  But remember:

  - You always need to `cmp` in the same direction (e.g. switch off to on).
  - Beware of this: [*Using the same file as stdin and stdout results in empty file*](https://superuser.com/q/645997/432690).
    `… | comm -12 - result1 > result1` is wrong.

---

Documentation:

- [`cmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html)
- [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html)

Comment: Thank you Kamil. This is a very helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Windows user and I've used Beyond Compare for many years for file compares, including comparing 3 files (2 at a time) to each other.

It appears that Beyond Compare also has a Linux distro, so you might want to check it out.

https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_linux_install

I know the Windows version has options to show just differences, as well as a lot of other features that might help you out. I can't remember if they have a 3 way compare or not.

I'm not dev or sales for them, I just like the software a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from Kamil, I used this to get what I needed:

cmp -l file1 file2 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' | sort > changes_12

cmp -l file3 file2 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' | sort > changes_32

comm -12 changes_12 changes_32 > common_changes